# django - queryset order_by field that has characters and integers

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model that has a field (lets call it `this_field`) which is stored as a `string`. The values in `this_field` are in the form `Char###` - as in, they have values such as: `A4` or `A34` or `A55` (note that they will always have the same first character).

Is there a way to select all the records and order them by this field? Currently, when I do an `.order_by('this_field')` I get the order like this:

`A1`
`A13`
`A2`
`A25`
etc...

What I want is:

`A1`
`A2`
`A13`
`A25`
etc...

Any best approach methods or solutions to achieve this query set ordered properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queryset ordering is handled by the database backend, not by Django.  This limits the options for changing the way that ordering is done.  You can either load all of the data and sort it with Python, or add additional options to your query to have the database use some kind of custom sorting by defining functions.

Use the queryset [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) function will allow you to do what you want by executing custom SQL for sorting, but at the expense of reduced portability.

In your example, it would probably suffice to split the input field into two sets of data, the initial character, and the remaining integer value.  You could then apply a sort to both columns.  Here's an example (untested):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()

# Add in a couple of extra SELECT columns, pulling apart this_field into
# this_field_a (the character portion) and this_field_b (the integer portion).

qs = qs.extra(select={
              'this_field_a': "SUBSTR(this_field, 1)",
              'this_field_b': "CAST(substr(this_field, 2) AS UNSIGNED)"})
```

The `extra` call adds two new fields into the `SELECT` call.  The first clause pulls out the first character of the field, the second clause converts the remainder of the field to an integer.

It should now be possible to `order_by` on these fields.  By specifying two fields to `order_by`, ordering applies to the character field first, then to the integer field.

eg

```
qs = qs.order_by('this_field_a', 'this_field_b')
```

This example should work on both MySql and SQLite.  It should also be possible to create a single extra field which is used only for sorting, allowing you to specify just a single field in the `order_by()` call.

Comment: That worked perfectly.Though I wonder if you edited your answer to add an extra closed bracket somewhere... I had to add one. Nevertheless, worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use this sort order a lot and on bigger tables you should think about two separate fields that contain the separated values:

1. the alpha values should be lowercased only, in a text or char field, with `db_index=True` set
2. the numeric values should be in an integer field with `db_index=True` set on them.

`qs.order_by('alpha_sort_field', 'numeric_sort_field')`

Otherwise you will probably experience some (or up to a huge) performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to sort the QuerySet based on the int part of `this_field`:

```
qs = ModelClass.objects.all()
sorted_qs = sorted(qs, key=lambda ModelClass: int(ModelClass.this_field[1:]))
```