# Django - order_by a queryset using the INT part of a field

Tags: python, sql, django

I have this query:

```
qs = MyObject.objects.all()
```

In my MyObject model I have `case_number` field. It's a CharField, the value is a combination of int and string like "123abc".

I want to order my queryset by the int part of `case_number` field. Example:

```
['34ohkj', '456kKJj', '12jk'] -> ['12jk', '34ohkj', '456kKJj']
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work because I can't remove the string part of `case_number`:

```
qs.annotate(case_number_int=Cast(F('case_number'), IntegerField())).order_by('case_number_int')
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django - queryset order\_by field that has characters and integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467920/django-queryset-order-by-field-that-has-characters-and-integers)

Comment: No, I received this error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "unsigned" does not exist`. In addition extra() is deprecated.

Comment: try looking into the pull requests for the [ticket #28805](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28805). Unfortunately its not fully done yet, otherwise your problem would have been quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
qs = MyObject.objects.all()

# I think this is the optimal solution. 

qs = qs.extra(select={
              'case_number_int': "Cast(F('case_number'), IntegerField()))"
    })
```

now you can perform an order by on this. for example
`qs = qs.order_by('case_number_int')`

Comment: That does not answer my question, I want to apply that in a queryset, not just on a simple string.

Comment: sorry about the previous answer. now I have made changes.